# IOKit: Creating a MacOS device instance to provide coordinate input for a USB-OTG device

Tags: iokit

I'm working on a project that involves connecting a single-board computer (either a BeagleBone Black, or a BeagleBoard X15) to a Mac via USB OTG, and then delivering basic mouse/touch input (pointer coordinates and left/right-click events).

This process should be technically very similar to connecting a mouse (or, more accurately, a touchscreen-style device that receives precise mouse coordinates) and passing some ordinary HID input to MacOS. So I don't need most of the complexity of IOKit - I don't think I need to create a kernel extension; I should just be able to create an instance of a HID for which MacOS already has generic kernel extensions.

So I'm delving into IOKit to figure out how to create the device instance and provide input. However, nearly everything I'm reading about IOKit involves creating and registering new kernel extensions, services, etc. - none of which is germane to my project.

So far, the only relevant leads I've got are the I/O Registry Explorer and the contents of /System/Library/Extensions. Several items in there look promising, such as AppleDHIDMouse.kext. However, I cannot find any examples of code to bridge the gap: how my USB-connected device can connect with the kernel extension, create an instance for itself, and send commands.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Either your device is fully USB HID compliant, in which case you shouldn't need any code at all on the Mac side, or you'll need to create a kernel extension.

How far have you got? What does your device look like in ioreg/IORegistryExplorer? (The latter is from the "Additional Tools for Xcode", downloadable from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ )

Does your USB device's interface report as HID? (bInterfaceClass 3) The device itself normally reports as a composite device (bDeviceType 0). bInterfaceProtocol and bInterfacSubClass also have defined meanings in the context of HID, and should probably both be 0 for a "tablet" style device. With that in place, macOS should pick up your device as a HID device and try to drive it with one of its built in HID device drivers.

The way HID devices work is through "reports" - event data structures with a flexible format/layout, which is defined via the device's "report descriptor". What buttons, input axes, etc. your device has is defined there.

For an example of a USB "tablet" device (absolute coordinate pointing device) that works with macOS, check out the [code for the USB Tablet device that Qemu emulates](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/c4fe9700e6bb769059608f768d2efd3d80a69630/hw/usb/dev-hid.c#L488). That might be a good starting point for the report descriptor of your own device.

If your device doesn't conform to general USB HID conventions and uses some custom protocol, you'll need a custom kext (up to macOS 10.14) or dext (from macOS 10.15 onwards) which will most likely implement a `IOHIDDevice` subclass. An example of such a driver is the [open source Mac driver for the Xbox 360's game controller](https://github.com/360Controller/360Controller), which doesn't behave like a standard USB HID device.